# How to use Arcgis map for offline (Android) and how to make .tpk file for offline use

Tags: android, maps, arcgis, esri

I am badly stuck in one problem related to map as i am using Esri Arcgis map offline for my android app and i have already used all the samples provided by esri arcgis map but finally i found that .tpk can be used for offline but i am not getting any solution to create .tpk file and seriously i didn't get any other solution except .tpk file creation. so i request if anyone know about it and used this before or may have any other solution to my problem, as it will be very helpful for me

NOTE : moto is to run map offline(with No internet connection).
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create a tile package is by using ArcGIS for Desktop. See [How to create a tile package](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-arcmap/how-to-create-a-tile-package.htm).

If you can't or won't use ArcGIS for Desktop, you can do it with ArcGIS Runtime code. See [Create an offline map](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/create-an-offline-map.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_286D33A9E13C4BFDA57428D9A0B88D22) for guidance. See the [Export Tile Cache sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/sample-code/export-tile-cache/) for details.

To display a tile package, create a new [`ArcGISLocalTiledLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/ags/ArcGISLocalTiledLayer.html) and add it to the map.

Comment: Hello Thanks for the reply but i have already tried all the above solution but have not get any positive result, please help me with brief steps if you know how to do it.

Comment: What result did you get when you tried both solutions I proposed? These solutions are known to work, so you need to provide some error messages or something useful if we're going to be able to help you.